# TeamCity starts build with schedule trigger even if trigger was disabled at scheduled time

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have a build with a schedule trigger for 6PM because I do not want this build to run outside of a specially-designated window. If I don't want this build to run at all, I disable the 6PM schedule trigger.

Fast forward to the next day, when I want it to resume running at 6PM. It's currently noon and I go back to the build and enable the schedule trigger mistakenly assuming it will wait to start until 6PM this evening.

What actually happens is the build is triggered immediately, I assume because it knows it would have started yesterday at 6PM had the trigger been enabled. This seems counterintuitive. How can I stop it from triggering a build immediately when I enable the trigger at a different time of day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused either by [TW-23632](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23632) or [TW-24783](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24783) which is fixed in newer releases. I'd recommend to upgrade to latest TeamCity version.